# Cambiar htacces por web.config para MVC

Tags: php, mvc, .htaccess

Desarrolle una sección en MVC usando *htacces*, pero el hosting donde esta alojado mi pagina es *Window ISS*, y usa el archivo `web.config`. He estado buscando la conversión de mi actual archivo y no consigo hacerlo funcionar.

Este es mi *htaccess*:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    ErrorDocument 404  http://urldemipagina.com/error/


    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?controller=$1&action=$2

</ifModule>
```

Si alguien me ofrece alguna guía le agradecería.

esto es lo que tngo en mi webconfig, que hasta ahora, todas las redirecciones
las hace al index

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
        <rule name="https://miurl.com/express" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
            <match url="*"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" 
                       negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" 
                     matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
             </rule></rules>
        </rewrite>
     </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
```

Comment: ¿Buscas redirigir tu web a un error en ese htaccess?

Comment: ese error es solo cuando no se encuentra la url ingresada. De resto, lo ideal es que  RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 sea el principal, recibiendo el controlador y la accion (metodo)

Comment: no comprendo, web.config es el archivo de configuración de .net, [esto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig) es lo que tienes que hacer

Comment: el mvc que yo tengo es puro php y js. Pasa que venia trabajando todo localmente con el htacces de apache, pero al subir al hosting me encontre con que es window

Comment: ¿El mvc lo escribiste tu? si no es así en su documentación debe haber una guía.

Comment: el mvc lo escribi yo. A cual documentacion te referis?

Answer (score 0):

Hay algunos detalles que corregir:

1. el atributo name del elemento rule es un nombre que identifica la ruta
2. para que todas las condiciones dentro de  sean requeridas debes agregar el atributo logicalGrouping="MatchAll"
3. el elemento match dentro del elemento rule utiliza un patron regex. He agregado un punto para indicar que puede ser cualquier carater
4. Por último, he agregado el atributo stopProcessing="true" al elemento rule para detener el procesamiento de las rules siguientes

Aquí el código

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Nombre descriptivo" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*"/>
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Espero te ayude, buena suerte!